# Почему после reset --hard "теряются" новые commit при переходе на точку раньше reset?

Tags: git

Изучаю **git** и основные команды(для локальной работы).
Предположим, у меня есть 5 коммитов:1,2,3,4,5. На 5-ом я понимаю, что 4-ый и 5-ый мне не нужны, решаю их удалить и делаю

```
Git reset --hard <hash_3>
```

Добавляю 6-ой (4-ый по новой истории) коммит. Делая **git log** вижу 4 коммита, все ок. Но если временно перемещусь на 3, 2, 1 коммит (git checkout ), **git log** покажет мне снова историю 1,2,3,4,5. И надо смотреть **reflog**, что бы перейти на крайний коммит.

Почему так не логично(в моем понимании) происходит, или я неправильно делаю откат? Не хочется плодить новые ветки и откатывать через **revert**, если я точно знаю, что коммиты 4 и 5 мне не нужны.

Comment: Что конкретно значит «временно перемещусь на 3 коммит»?

Comment: @AlexeyTen git checkout <hash_3(2,1)>, хочу посмотреть код в этот момент времени, уточнил в вопросе

Comment: Синтаксис у вас неправильный, пробелов между минусами и hard не должно быть `git reset --hard 12345`

Comment: *надо смотреть reflog*. достаточно `$ git checkout ветка-в-которой-вы-перед-этим-работали`

Comment: Нужны уточнения. Покажите полную историю работы, т.е. какие команды выполнялись. После `git checkout <hash_3>` никак `git log` не может показать комиты 4 и 5, если делался `git reset --hard <hash_3>`.

Comment: @fantomrik редактор здесь отображает то что вы напечатали. Пожалуйста исправьте текст вопроса так что бы никому не приходилось гадать где у вас тут опечатка, а где ошибка

Answer (score 1):

`git reset` НЕ УДАЛЯЕТ коммиты. Он всего лишь возвращает состояние указанного коммита. Т.е. просто ставит указатель на соответствующий коммит в истории.

Answer (score 1):

Вы явно что-то не договариваете.

```
$ git log --oneline 
5f54064 (HEAD -> master) commit5
de94234 commit4
cee22a8 commit3
46fb53b commit2
40b7366 commit1

$ git reset --hard cee22a8
HEAD is now at cee22a8 commit3

$ git commit --allow-empty -m commit4-new
[master 87d853a] commit4-new

$ git log --oneline 
87d853a (HEAD -> master) commit4-new
cee22a8 commit3
46fb53b commit2
40b7366 commit1

$ git checkout cee22a8
Note: switching to 'cee22a8'.
... bla-bla-bla
HEAD is now at cee22a8 commit3

$ git log --oneline 
cee22a8 (HEAD) commit3
46fb53b commit2
40b7366 commit1
```

Comment: Да, я неверно описал в вопросе последовательность действий. Сначала делал checkout на hash, потом уже ресет, и в итоге получал неожиданный результат. Покажу его в своем ответе, возможно кому то будет интересно.
Про пробел после неверно прочел ваше сообщение, подумал вы пишете что пробел у меня между  дефисами. Удалил свои сообщения, что бы не путать ни кого

Answer (score 0):

Я в вопросе ввел в заблуждение с последовательностью своих действий, поэтому получал непредсказуемые (для меня на тот момент) результаты. Делал так:

```
$ git log --pretty=format:'%h %ad | %s%d [%an]' --graph --date=short
* bb4ec58 2020-06-09 | 5 (HEAD -> master) 
* 4fc3943 2020-06-09 | 4 
* b5c9977 2020-06-09 | 3 
* f9ebe93 2020-06-09 | 2 
* 564d96f 2020-06-09 | 1 

$ git checkout b5c9977
Note: switching to 'b5c9977'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:

  git switch -c <new-branch-name>

Or undo this operation with:

  git switch -

Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false

HEAD is now at b5c9977 3

$ git reset --hard b5c9977
HEAD is now at b5c9977 3


$ git log --pretty=format:'%h %ad | %s%d [%an]' --graph --date=short
* b5c9977 2020-06-09 | 3 (HEAD) 
* f9ebe93 2020-06-09 | 2 
* 564d96f 2020-06-09 | 1 

$ git add 1

$ git commit -m "4(6)"
[detached HEAD 83ac362] 4(6)
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

$ git log --pretty=format:'%h %ad | %s%d [%an]' --graph --date=short
* 83ac362 2020-06-09 | 4(6) (HEAD) 
* b5c9977 2020-06-09 | 3 
* f9ebe93 2020-06-09 | 2 
* 564d96f 2020-06-09 | 1 

$ git checkout master
Warning: you are leaving 1 commit behind, not connected to
any of your branches:

  83ac362 4(6)

If you want to keep it by creating a new branch, this may be a good time
to do so with:

 git branch <new-branch-name> 83ac362

Switched to branch 'master'

$ git log --pretty=format:'%h %ad | %s%d [%an]' --graph --date=short
* bb4ec58 2020-06-09 | 5 (HEAD -> master) 
* 4fc3943 2020-06-09 | 4 
* b5c9977 2020-06-09 | 3 
* f9ebe93 2020-06-09 | 2 
* 564d96f 2020-06-09 | 1
```

Вчера прочел замечательное описание [Раскрытие тайн reset](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD-reset#r_git_reset) и вроде разобрался в вопросе. Нужно следить не только за **HEAD**, но и на какой commit указывает **breanch**.

Как итог по решению моей задачи (удалению коммитов в локальном git) можно или просто делать **git reset --hard** , но надо следить, что бы **HEAD** и **branch** указывали до **reset** на один и тот же **commit**.

```
$ git log --pretty=format:'%h %ad | %s%d [%an]' --graph --date=short
* bb4ec58 2020-06-09 | 5 (HEAD -> master) 
* 4fc3943 2020-06-09 | 4 
* b5c9977 2020-06-09 | 3 
* f9ebe93 2020-06-09 | 2 
* 564d96f 2020-06-09 | 1 

$ git reset --hard b5c9977
HEAD is now at b5c9977 3

$ git log --pretty=format:'%h %ad | %s%d [%an]' --graph --date=short
* b5c9977 2020-06-09 | 3 (HEAD -> master) 
* f9ebe93 2020-06-09 | 2 
* 564d96f 2020-06-09 | 1 

$ git add 1

$ git commit -m "4(6)"
[master 2e410df] 4(6)
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

$ git log --pretty=format:'%h %ad | %s%d [%an]' --graph --date=short
* 2e410df 2020-06-09 | 4(6) (HEAD -> master) 
* b5c9977 2020-06-09 | 3 
* f9ebe93 2020-06-09 | 2 
* 564d96f 2020-06-09 | 1 

$ git checkout master
Already on 'master'

$ git log --pretty=format:'%h %ad | %s%d [%an]' --graph --date=short
* 2e410df 2020-06-09 | 4(6) (HEAD -> master) 
* b5c9977 2020-06-09 | 3 
* f9ebe93 2020-06-09 | 2 
* 564d96f 2020-06-09 | 1
```

Или создавать новую ветку с нужного **commit**, удалять основную ветку и переименовывать текущую в изначальную ветку (для перфекционизма).

Так же можно почистить историю **reflog** через

```
$ git reflog expire --all
```

Comment: `git reset --hard` «сбрасывает» текущую ветку, но когда вы сделали `git checkout b5c9977` у вас больше нет текущей ветки о чём git весьма многословно намекает. В частности *you can [...] **without impacting any branches** by switching back to a branch*